# what are mysql sessions used in isolation level

Tags: php, mysql, session, transactions, isolation-level

I am reading about isolation level in mysql database, while reading I came across the following syntax

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] TRANSACTION
    transaction_characteristic [, transaction_characteristic] ...

transaction_characteristic:
    ISOLATION LEVEL level
  | READ WRITE
  | READ ONLY

level:
     REPEATABLE READ
   | READ COMMITTED
   | READ UNCOMMITTED
   | SERIALIZABLE
```

reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html

My question is, in 1st line of syntax, `SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] TRANSACTION`, what is `GLOBAL` and `SESSION` keywords. Can anyone explain it with example ?

Can we start Transaction in particular session(through PHP or any other language)? or they are managed by mysql only ?

Comment: `session` is the connection running the command. e.g. you. `global` is just that... everything/everywhere.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if you know what that command does. It does not START a transaction. It sets the (default) values for your (or in case of global: anyones) next transactions (or in case neither global nor session is given, transaction (without the s)).

Comment: But what if I want to start particular transaction in particular session. Is this possible ?